# JQuery getting dynamic values and populate hidden form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of divs that load each has a dynamic id name based on a database result.

Within each div are several hidden input text fields that all have the same name and id.

The user clicks a href which is dynamically generated from the database launching colorbox. For example ()

On the opening div is a button. When the user clicks this button it submits a form.

As it is now it sumbits only the values of the first instance of the fields (for example Yellow, digital-world, Digital Revolution).

It is suppsoed to submit the values of the url that is active. For example, if the user clicks (">) then it should submit Blue, abstract, Abstract Panel. Instead of Yellow, digital-world, Digital Revolution.

In addition, there are scroll buttons on the colorbox so for example the user can click a next button to load the next set of values. Ie. if he is on  and clicks the next button he is suddenly on  so if he clicks the button on here it should submit the correct values ie. Blue, abstract, Abstract Panel.

Does this make sense?

Let me show...

```
<div class="doneit">
<div style="float:left;"><a href="#container" id="02_Digital_Revolution_Yellow" target="Yellow" title="digital-world" class="lightbox-image inline"><img src="/videos/digital-world/Yellow/02_Digital_Revolution_Yellow.jpg" ></a></div>
div class="doit"><a href="http://www.url.com/folder/212.htm" class="playvideo"></a></div>
<div style="height:70px;"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="Product_Vid_1" name="Product_Vid_1" value="Yellow">
<input type="hidden" id="Product_Dir_1" name="Product_Dir_1" value="digital-world">
<input type="hidden" id="Product_Name_1" name="Product_Name_1" value="Digital Revolution">
</div>          

<div class="doneit">
<div style="float:left;"><a href="#container" id="06_Abstract_Panel_Blue" target="Blue" title="abstract" class="lightbox-image inline"><img src="/videos/abstract/Blue/06_Abstract_Panel_Blue.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="doit"><a href="http://www.url.com/folder/349.htm" class="playvideo"></a></div>
<div style="height:70px;"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="Product_Vid_1" name="Product_Vid_1" value="Blue">
<input type="hidden" id="Product_Dir_1" name="Product_Dir_1" value="abstract">
<input type="hidden" id="Product_Name_1" name="Product_Name_1" value="Abstract Panel">  
</div>          

<div class="doneit">
<div style="float:left;"><a href="#container" id="10_Abstract_Discs_Red" target="Red" title="abstract" class="lightbox-image inline"><img src="/videos/abstract/Red/10_Abstract_Discs_Red.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="doit"><a href="http://www.url.com/folder/353.htm" class="playvideo"></a></div>
<div style="height:70px;"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="Product_Vid_1" name="Product_Vid_1" value="Red">
<input type="hidden" id="Product_Dir_1" name="Product_Dir_1" value="abstract">
<input type="hidden" id="Product_Name_1" name="Product_Name_1" value="Abstract Disks">  
</div>          

<div class="doneit">
<div style="float:left;"><a href="#container" id="electric-purple-grid" target="Purple" title="electric-effect" class="lightbox-image inline"><img src="/videos/electric-effect/Purple/electric-purple-grid.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="doit"><a href="http://www.url.com/folder/129.htm" class="playvideo"></a></div>
<div style="height:70px;"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="Product_Vid_1" name="Product_Vid_1" value="Purple">
<input type="hidden" id="Product_Dir_1" name="Product_Dir_1" value="electric-effect">
<input type="hidden" id="Product_Name_1" name="Product_Name_1" value="Electric Grid">       
</div>

<div style="display:none">
<div id="container"><div id="video"></div>
<div id="doesit">

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitMyForm(){
$('#Product_color_16').val($('#Product_Vid_1').val());
$('#Product_Dir_16').val($('#Product_Dir_1').val());
$('#Product_Name_16').val($('#Product_Name_1').val());
$('#myform').submit();
}
</script>

<form name="myform" action="/thisurl.asp" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="Product_color_16" name="Product_color_16" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="Product_Dir_16" name="Product_Dir_16" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="Product_Name_16" name="Product_Name_16" value="">

<button class="addtobutton addtocart" onclick="submitMyForm();"></button>

</form>

</div></div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Sorry...some of the explanation code got lost in the text....

It is supposed to submit the values of the url that is active. 

For example, if the user clicks on the div containing 

    <a href="http://www.url.com/folder/349.htm" class="playvideo"></a>

then it should submit Blue, abstract, Abstract Panel and not the values of Yellow, digital-world, Digital Revolution which it is doing in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple elements sharing the same ID - which is wrong and can cause you lots of problems.

One of the problems is exactly the one you're facing now.

As you don't have a unique ID for the elements, the code will consider just the first match (in your case, the "Yellow" ones)

To fix this? Let's leave as much as possible with jQuery, to make it simple. Also, let's fix a bit the HTML markup. Please refer to the comments.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Removed all the input ids, because they were duplicated and useless. If you really need them for something else, make them unique. -->

<div class="doneit">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <a href="#container" id="02_Digital_Revolution_Yellow" target="Yellow" title="digital-world" class="lightbox-image inline">
            <img src="/videos/digital-world/Yellow/02_Digital_Revolution_Yellow.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="doit">
        <a href="http://www.url.com/folder/212.htm" class="playvideo"></a>
    </div>
    <div style="height:70px;"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="Product_Vid_1" value="Yellow" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Product_Dir_1" value="digital-world" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Product_Name_1" value="Digital Revolution" />
</div>

<div class="doneit">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <a href="#container" id="06_Abstract_Panel_Blue" target="Blue" title="abstract" class="lightbox-image inline">
            <img src="/videos/abstract/Blue/06_Abstract_Panel_Blue.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="doit">
        <a href="http://www.url.com/folder/349.htm" class="playvideo"></a>
    </div>
    <div style="height:70px;"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="Product_Vid_1" value="Blue" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Product_Dir_1" value="abstract" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Product_Name_1" value="Abstract Panel" />
</div>

<div class="doneit">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <a href="#container" id="10_Abstract_Discs_Red" target="Red" title="abstract" class="lightbox-image inline">
            <img src="/videos/abstract/Red/10_Abstract_Discs_Red.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="doit">
        <a href="http://www.url.com/folder/353.htm" class="playvideo"></a>
    </div>
    <div style="height:70px;"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="Product_Vid_1" value="Red" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Product_Dir_1" value="abstract" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Product_Name_1" value="Abstract Disks" />
</div>

<div class="doneit">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <a href="#container" id="electric-purple-grid" target="Purple" title="electric-effect" class="lightbox-image inline">
            <img src="/videos/electric-effect/Purple/electric-purple-grid.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="doit">
        <a href="http://www.url.com/folder/129.htm" class="playvideo"></a>
    </div>
    <div style="height:70px;"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="Product_Vid_1" value="Purple" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Product_Dir_1" value="electric-effect" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Product_Name_1" value="Electric Grid" />
</div>

<div style="display:none">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="video"></div>
        <div id="doesit">
            <form name="myform" action="/thisurl.asp" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" id="Product_color_16" name="Product_color_16" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" id="Product_Dir_16" name="Product_Dir_16" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" id="Product_Name_16" name="Product_Name_16" value="" />

                <!-- You can just ommit the onclick here. It's gonna work automatically, because it's a submit type. -->

                <button class="addtobutton addtocart" type="submit"></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery (Javascript):**

```
// Add this bit to your page header, straight into the HTML markup (wrapped
// into script tags) or save into a separate JS file. Up to you.

var setFormValues = function(div) {

    // Getting the inputs values. The ones within the clicked div.
    // We look for the inputs which name starts with Product_...
    // Let's use .prop() instead of .val() because IE sometimes doesn's like it.

    var div = $(div);
    var productVid = $("input[name^='Product_Vid_']", div).prop("value");
    var productDir = $("input[name^='Product_Dir_']", div).prop("value");
    var productName = $("input[name^='Product_Name_']", div).prop("value");

    // Setting the form inputs values.

    $("#Product_color_16").prop("value", productVid);
    $("#Product_Dir_16").prop("value", productDir);
    $("#Product_Name_16").prop("value", productName);     
}

$(function () {

    // When the user clicks on one of the divs.

    $(".doneit").on("click", function () {
        setFormValues($(this));    

        return true;        
    });   

    // When the user clicks the cart button, on the video window.

    $(".addtocart").on("click", function() {

        // Here we need a bit of native Javascript.

        var videoPlaying = document.getElementById("video_video");

        if (typeof videoPlaying != "undefined") {
           var videoSource = videoPlaying.currentSrc;

           if (typeof videoSource != "undefined") {

               var videoSourceFilename = videoSource.split("com/")[1].split(".")[0];

               // Check which div has an image which src 
               // matches the video filename.

               var image = $(document).find("img[src*='" + videoSourceFilename + "']");

               if (typeof image != "undefined") {
                   var divContainer = $(image).parent().parent().parent();

                   if (typeof divContainer != "undefined")
                       setFormValues($(divContainer));
               }
           }
        }

        return true;
    });     
});
```

Comment: Hi MelanciaUK, 
I see I'm out of my league here....

I tried the code you suggested but it doesn't seem to sumbit any values at all? Then I wondered if it was an error where you wrote 'input[name^="Product_Vid"] etc instead of 'input[name^="Product_Vid_1"]...but no that didn't work either.

Is there something I'm not seeing...overlooking? I could show you the actual URL...but I don't think my boss would allow me to share the URL on public. 

Dman this jquery...killing me all day :(

Comment: Removed the ID's also. Still no values being submitted. Any ideas?

Comment: Your HTML markup has some other problems. Some tags are not closed and it's causing the script to fail. I'm looking here what I can do.

Comment: I see the div class="doit" in the first section is a fault from copying Melancia. In the actual code theres a < before it. Sorry...its not so easy posting with 4 spaces in front of everything ;)

Comment: Hahahahaha I get it. I'm trying here a better solution. Just a second.

Comment: You're really kind Melancia. Really appreciate you taking time like this. Hope it's possible to figure it out. Been driving me nuts all day!

Comment: WOW...This is SOOOOOOO close! It's working when you click on the DIV itself but it's not working when you scroll through the colorbox so for example the user can click a next button to load the next set of values and it keeps the values that were first clicked...arrrgghhhh....it is really frustrating this jquery stuff Melancia

Comment: It's monitoring the click on the link, the one that points to `#container`. Which element should it be instead?

Comment: I really appreciate everything you are doing Melancia and I don't want to waste your time since I'm really a web designer not programmer so I'm gonna send you the link so you can see yourself.

Comment: It's quite an easy change actually.

Comment: if you take a look at www.123ppt.com look at the video backgrounds section on the home page. there's 4 videos if you click one then the addtocart button on the colorbox works. if you scroll forward to the next video or back to the one before etc. and press the button you still get the values from the first click.

Comment: Will have a look. Give my updated answer another try in the meantime.

Comment: You need to work out the previous/next buttons too. You didn't mention this in your question. And the big problem here is that they're generated by some other plugin.

Comment: Tried moving up to the parent class but nothing submits Melancia

Comment: Sorry Melancia, I tried to write, In addition, there are scroll buttons on the colorbox so for example the user can click a next button to load the next set of values. But I guess now the functionality moves to the click its different to the solution I was origianlly thinking. I thought if it was possible to get the values of #Product_color_16, #Product_Dir_16 etc of the "div" that was active i.e. playing in the div id="container"

Comment: Try this latest update. I can't test it because I don't have the videos. Hope it works.

Comment: No sorry Melancia...no values being sent :(

Comment: I think you'll need to give it a go from here then. The basic is there, maybe it needs a bit of tweaking. Sorry.

Comment: Checking your page source, there's an error on the div class: `class="ppt-vidpresentation%>"`.

Comment: When you fix this, give the answer another try. I've changed it a bit.

Comment: I hope so. :P Hahahahaha

Comment: Listen Melancia...we need to do something about this. You've been working your ass off. I need to get the boss to send a few £ over to you. How to do it? PayPal or something?

Comment: Did you publish the latest changes? I can't see them on the site.

Comment: No...I can try them now. Hang on.

Comment: Nope...it seems to be just pulling the video i clicked on originally.

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing the same here. But it's nearly there. Just a second.

Comment: I was making a primary mistake on Javascript. Try it now.

Comment: Same thing only submitting the original clicked?

Comment: The funny thing is, running on the site it gives an error when using `.split()`, and if I try exactly the same on the console, it just works.

Comment: Isn't this the joys of programming? ;) hehe

Comment: Sure it is. :) Let's try again.

Comment: Arrrghhh! ...nope same thing my friend.

Comment: When you click previous/next, the video isn't still there, that's why the script can't find it. Trying to think on something else.

Comment: Now it's a shot in the dark. I'm not sure the video change will trigger the event handler. Worth it a try.

Comment: And don't forget to change one of the .doneit on the script. I can see it on the site source.

Comment: Wasn't there one of the tests near the start that was working Melancia? But you wanted to try something else? I tried it and it worked and i wrote Shit and Bacon...looking back at the thread...it was about an hour ago?

Comment: Let me know when you publish the latest one. That's the end of my hopes.

Comment: Hang on...let me look back...we could end up kicking ourselves here.

Comment: its not adding anything Melancia

Comment: Paste it again. I've left an extra `)` by mistake.

Comment: Nope it's still not happy...no values posting

Comment: Can you see the `video` element with id `video_video` in your code? I just need to know this to carry on.

Comment: you need to help me a little Melancia...its not my code so i dont know where am I looking?

Comment: videoPlayer = document.getElementById("video_video");

Comment: if i view source of the home page and search for video_video the only instance is in your function.

Comment: Alright then. Give the answer a try then. Let's see what happens.

Comment: its posting values again...but stil only the first clicked.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that. I'll give a break now and come back later with some other idea. I didn't give up!

Comment: I am really impressed. I hope you know that. I really am. You're like the Terminator! ...Melanciator?

Comment: Hahahahaha I like challenges. That's part of my job.

Comment: This must be like a Bear Grylls thing Melancinator ;)

Comment: YOU'RE BACK...heheheit seems it freezes the ability to play so you can't open the player

Comment: Seems the script is caught in a loop or something?

Comment: I was expecting for that actually. Different approach now. You'll need to check the answer for a change to another script. It won't be difficult to find it on your page. And then, change the script we've been fighting with aswell.

Comment: Hi there, ok I changed them...but it seems when I click a video now it opens a new tab and loads the page?

Comment: Just comment off that line on the other script, and I'll think about something else later. I gotta go now.

Comment: No problem Melanciator ;) I undertstand...listen thanks for everything so far man. Really really appreciate everything like I said. I have to show thisw thread to my boss so he can see what you've been doing.

Comment: No worries mate. And it was just a damn extra double quotes at the end. You can give it another try.

Comment: Morning! Hahahaha Just remove that change we've done to the other script and use this updated answer. I believe it's all good now.

Comment: :( nope...same story Melancia

Comment: Oh no...have we hit the wall on this thing M?

Comment: There was just a typo there. I've typed "/com" instead of "com/". Try it again...

Comment: Wish I could do this stuff M...it must be a bit frustrating when you see a typo and you know its a typo...i see the code and i just think...jesus...how does he come up with this?!?!? :)

Comment: Hmmm...you're definetly onto something here now...when i click the first video it adds the last one. If I use the prev/ next button its adding the last one as well. So there's something different?

Comment: Let me debug it now. It was supposed to change the values when you click on one of the videos (as before), and then update these values when you click the add to cart button, based on the video that's playing.

Comment: Fingers crossed here. Try it again, please.

Comment: Just so you know, my fingers, toes, balls...everything is crossed...there's no blood circulation in the lower half of my body now! ;)

Comment: I can't believe that. Please double check multiple times. Hahahaha

Comment: I am... :) ...hang on...i think i've wet myself! ;) hehe

Comment: OMG....I don't know what to say M...Is there a small temple i can go to to worship you? ;) hehe

Comment: All joking and stuff aside...we need to talk...how can we do that?

Comment: I'm glad it finally worked. It's a bit hard to try/test when you don't have the whole project in your hands. :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as the solution, if you're happy with it. :)